# What is the significance of data-config.xml file in Solr?

Tags: apache, solr

and when shall I use it? How is it configured can anyone please tell me in detail?

Answer (score 1):

The `data-config.xml` file is an example configuration file for [how to use the DataImportHandler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler) in Solr. It's one way of getting data into Solr, allowing one of the servers to connect through JDBC (or through a few other plugins) to a database server or a set of files and import them into Solr.

DIH has a few issues (for example the non-distributed way it works), so it's usually suggested to write the indexing code yourself (and POST it to Solr from a suitable client, such as SolrJ, Solarium, SolrClient, MySolr, etc.)

It has been mentioned that the DIH functionality really should be moved into a separate application, but that hasn't happened yet as far as I know.